# What is the best code template facility for Emacs?

Tags: emacs, template-engine, code-snippets

Particularly, what is the best snippets package out there?

Features:

- easy to define new snippets (plain text, custom input with defaults)
- simple navigation between predefined positions in the snippet
- multiple insertion of the same custom input
- accepts currently selected text as a custom input
- *cross-platform* (Windows, Linux)
- dynamically evaluated expressions (embedded code) written in a concise programming language (Perl, Python, Ruby are preferred)
- nicely coexists with others packages in Emacs

Example of code template, a simple `for` loop in C:

```
for (int i = 0; i < %N%; ++i) {
  _
}
```

It is a lot of typing for such common code. I want to invoke a code template or snippet which inserts
that boilerplate code for me. Additionally it stops (on TAB or other keystroke) at `%N%` (my input replaces it) and final position of the cursor is `_`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[TextMate's snippets](http://manual.macromates.com/en/snippets) is the most closest match but it is not a cross-platform solution and not for Emacs.

The second closest thing is [YASnippet](http://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/) ([screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOj7btx3ATg) shows the main capabilities). But it interferes with `hippie-expand` package in my setup and the embedded language is EmacsLisp which I'm not comfortable with outside `.emacs`.

**EDIT**: Posted my answer here to allow voting on `YASnippet`.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I've been using Dmacro for years (ftp://ftp.sgi.com/other/dmacro/dmacro.tar.gz).

Here's a review of it that also mentions some alternatives: http://linuxgazette.net/issue39/marsden.html

Answer (score 4):

The EmacsWiki has a [page of template engines](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/CategoryTemplates).

Of these, I've used [tempo](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/TempoMode) in the (distant) past to add table support to [html-helper-mode](http://www.nongnu.org/baol-hth/), but don't know how it has progressed in the last 15 years.

Answer (score 3):

I'd add my vote for [tempo snippets](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TempoSnippets) ... easy to setup, powerful (you can run arbitrary elisp in your template - so that you can downcase things, lookup filenames & classes, count things, etc), set the indentation, integrate with abbrevs ... I use it a lot ;)

Answer (score 2):

I vote for http://cedet.sourceforge.net/srecode.shtml

It has very clean syntax and has access to code environment through `Semantic`.

Also it is a part of a large well supported `CEDET` distribution (which was built into Emacs for 24.x version series).

**UPDATE** [YASnippet](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet) is also a powerful template engine. But it uses an ugly file naming schema (your file name === template name) for you can't put several templates into a single file and have issues with national character sets...

Answer (score 1):

You can try a lightweight solution [muban.el](https://github.com/jiahaowork/muban.el)

It is written completely in Elisp and has a very simple syntax.