# Can I make some text to load automatically whenever I open a file in Emacs?

Tags: c++, emacs, text-editor

I am a user of emacs but basically I use the basic commands. I do some competitive coding and for every problem that I solve in C++ I have to write

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{


return 0;
}
```

before I start writing the solution. I was wondering that the mighty text Editor like Emacs must have some feature to pre include a text of string.

Comment: You should look a this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61446/what-is-the-best-code-template-facility-for-emacs Snippets are the way to go at this.

Comment: Why do you need `<iostream>` _and_ `<stdio.h>`?

Comment: Just an old habit give access to both cin, cout and scanf, printf ..